# MKMapView refresh map after removing annotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation

I have the following function in an extension of MKMapView that let me reload a specific annotation and keep it selected if needed and the issue is every time the `self.removeAnnotation` is called, the whole map is reloaded (or at least all the pins "jumped" as if a reload occurred)

Is there a way to achieve a reload of a **single** annotation without having the visual of a whole map reloading ?

```
 func reloadAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation, keepSelection: Bool = true) {
        let isSelected = selectedAnnotations.contains(where: annotation.isEqual(_:))
        //already tried **UIView.performWithoutAnimation** which decrease the jumping effect
        // UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
          self.removeAnnotation(annotation)
          self.addAnnotation(annotation)
        // }
        guard isSelected && keepSelection else {
            return
        }
        self.selectedAnnotations.append(annotation)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the unwanted "whole map reloading" visual effect comes from the recalculation of clusters which is triggered by `self.removeAnnotation(annotation)` and `self.addAnnotation(annotation)`.

So you have to avoid this methods if you just want to update some visual information.

My assumption is that your callout and/or title changed dynamically while selected and you reload because you want to render the changed callout information.

```
func reloadAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation, keepSelection: Bool = true) {
    let annotationView = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MyCoolAnnotationView
    if let annotationView {
        // do stuff like
        annotationView.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

`annotationView` will be nil if the annotation is not in the visible region or part of a cluster. In that case you don't want to reload anyways.

Instead of `annotationView.setNeedsLayout()` you might call your own method that does whatever you want.